# how to connect zkteco k40 with PHP(attendance device)

Tags: php, zkteco

I want to connect ZKteco k40 with php on xammp localhost to get attendance data
what I'm doing write now

1. Given ip address to zk40 192.168.1.201, subnet mask 255.255.255.0,
   gateway 0.0.0.0, DHCP off, passaword 0
2. Connected the device to pc(windows) with LAN(rj45)
3. Given static ip to the pc 192.168.1.200
4. when i ping 192.168.1.201, I get a reply back
5. I tired using zklibrary https://github.com/kamshory/ZKLibrary
   but test.php doesn't work showing nothing, used another library https://github.com/dnaextrim/php_zklib/tree/master/zklib, still cant get through

also note that I've installed zktime.net 3.0 and it worked perfectly

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me pls if you managed to connect to the ZKTeco device? I'm having the same issue, the connection goes in timeout. Thanks

Comment: Same issue with me

Answer (score 0):

zktime.net 3.0 is working based on the Web API (HTTP) communication. The libraries you have listed are working on simple TCP/IP socket programming. Web API document from http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html.

Answer (score 0):

zklib requires PHP Socket extension enabled.

Enable by adding `extension=php_sockets.dll` in `php.ini`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php

Answer (score -3):

I have a solution that works for me.

I download attendance manually from the machine software and the software store all the records in an MS Access DB file I read all records from DB file and store in my MySQL.